# Bringing user to ratings page of my app causes the program to crash (Only on certain devices)

Tags: android, android-intent

In my `onStart()` method of my `Activity`, I set the `onClickListener` of my `ImageView` to the following:

```
rate_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SoundManager.play(SoundManager.SOUND.app_button_touch);
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + GameActivity.current_context.getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
            // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            GameActivity.current_context.startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            GameActivity.current_context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + GameActivity.current_context.getPackageName())));
        }
    }
});
```

I've testing this on my Galaxy S8 100 times, and it never crashed because of this. In the crash reports from google play console, it said that this happened only certain Android devices and Android versions: Android 5.0 (10 events), Android 6.0 (2 events), and Android 4.4 (1 event). Here's an example of an `AndroidRuntimeException` I'm getting:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:1610)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:1597)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:337)
  at com.mannanstudios.memorywarp.ImageLoader$20.onClick (ImageLoader.java:620)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5197)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:20909)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1399)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

What could possibly be causing these crashes? It was reported that this crash only happened in this specific `onClick`, on the line `Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);` I am new to Android development so if I missed any other relevant information, please let me know what to add.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're starting your `Activity` looks unreliable to me as it's not clear if `GameActivity.current_context` is set properly or not. To make it easier retrieve a `Context` from your `View`. In your case, it's an `Activity` your `View` belongs to. So, the code could look as follows:

```
rate_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SoundManager.play(SoundManager.SOUND.app_button_touch);
        try {
        // use a context of your view instead
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + v.getContext().getPackageName());
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
        // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
        goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        // use a context of your view instead
        v.getContext().startActivity(goToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + v.getContext().getPackageName())));
    }


    }
});
```

Comment: `GameActivity.current_context` was set to `getApplicationContext()` in `GameActivity`s `onStart`. Instead I changed it to just `this`, and it works now. You were right, thanks!